# Circular ring of 19 cells. Find minimum number of targets to make all inactive.

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, puzzle

> Imagine a circular ring of 19 cells. Each cell has a coronavirus inside it: either active or inactive. Scientists have developed a special drug that can target a specific cell (of your choice). When the drug hits its target, it affects not only the targeted cell but also its 2 neighbors! The effect of the drug on these three cells is unusual: if the coronavirus in that cell was active, it become inactive; if the coronavirus in that cell wsa inactive, it become active! In other words, one dose of a drug toggles the state of 3 coronaviruses in 3 adjacent cells.
> If all coronaviruses are active in the initial state, is there a sequence of drug targets so that all coronaviruses become inactive at the same time? What is the length of the smallest such sequence?

This puzzle is from https://gurmeet.net/puzzles/nineteen-coronaviruses/index.html

SPOILER ALERT: The solution is present here at this link.

My approach: I realised if N was a multiple of 3, then best would be to hit every 3rd element. But another observation was that I thought of probably smaller N first eg 4,5,6,..3k+1 particularly and realised N would be the answer here. But I am looking for a more sophisticated approach. The first part is discoverable, that the sequence is permutation invariant. So, we remove duplicates as well. Till this, it is fine. But next step comes off a bit weird to me. How did they come up with this? Why isn't something like 011 allowed? Is it because it follows a linear sequence rather than circular so since this results in left 0 being active so we don't allow this?

Comment: If you did $011$, then the middle cell of those three would have been toggled twice, once for the $1$ in the middle, once for the $1$ on the right. But toggling twice is the same as doing nothing, meaning the middle cell is still inactive. The goal is to activate all cells, so you the solution vector cannot contain $011$.